# Set event reminders in android with data fetched via webservice call

Tags: android

I am working on a small project. We need to do the following:

1. Have a background service/whatever running on your android ph which
   listens for a sms with some specific content in the msg body
2. On encountering that specific content, make a webservice call to a
   remote server to download some event data
3. Set the fetched event data as reminders in the calendar

All the above must be done without any user interaction.

I have managed to do `#1` via a broadcast receiver. Didn't need to run a service for it.

For `#2`, I plan to call the web service via the Broadcast receivers onReceive() method and get the data. Once I have the data, how do I go about setting the same so that the user gets his/her timely reminders based on the same? There is no activity opening up or anything that the user can see. He should just get the reminders (even if he restarts the ph).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> For #2, I plan to call the web service via the Broadcast receivers onReceive() method and get the data.

Please don't. This will be unreliable and will freeze your UI if you happen to have the foreground activity. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread, and Android will terminate your code if it thinks you are spending too much time on that thread, even in the background. Please delegate this work to an `IntentService`, which has a background thread and automatically shuts down when there is no more work to be done.

> Once I have the data, how do I go about setting the same so that the user gets his/her timely reminders based on the same?

On Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0), you could add events to their calendar.

Before that, roll your own reminder mechanism using `AlarmManager`.

> There is no activity opening up or anything that the user can see.

You have no choice but to supply an activity. Otherwise, your app will never run on Android 3.1+. They will need to run your activity once to enable your app, then again every time after they elect to kill off your app via a task killer or the Settings application.

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion. Will change the code accordingly. Target version is Android 2.3. Any sample code or links on how to do the reminder thing using AlarmManager or anything else for 2.3?

Comment: @NimittoGanguli: I have a daily reminder as part of the LunchList app built up in [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials). See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-lunchlist/tree/master/20-Notification (in particular `OnBootReceiver` and `OnAlarmReceiver`).